# how to get total count of datasource in Devextreme

Tags: mobile, datasource, devextreme

I have a project in DevExtreme,mobile.

JavaScript:

```js
var example = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({

    store: example.db.deneme,

    requireTotalCount: true

}).load().done(function (result) {

        alert(result.length);
});
// this
```

In this code, '`result.length`' returns the correct answer.

How to get total count ('`result.length`') in '`this`' place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` method of the dataSource works asynchronously. So, you can use the deferred object to implement your scenario:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

example.load().done(function (result, extra) {
    deferred.resolve(extra.totalCount);
});

$.when(deferred).done(function(count){
    alert(count);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edgc42ga/

Comment: Hi Sergey, That is the answer I was looking for. Thank you for your answer. When I use more than one DataSource, they look different in order. Why ?

Comment: To resolve a few deferred objects call `$.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function(/* your deferreds */){})`, http://jsfiddle.net/1oczhvrf/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer